# Beats Audio equalizer does not work in HP laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, drivers

I have an HP Envy Ultrabook 4 laptop (Model# 4-1161er) equipped with the Beats Audio system. Several days ago I detected that its equalizer does not work. After crawling the specialized HP support forum I saw that it is a common problem for this hardware/software. However, none of the published recipes helped to solve the problem (such as removing recent Windows updates or reinstalling the IDT audio driver).

My OS was Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. Yesterday I upgraded to Windows 10, but the equalizer still does not work. The Beats Audio control panel version is the following:

[image: Beats Audio control panel version]

Some users insist that the problem is in the registry settings as they encountered the same problem after installing 3rd party software. I found one [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/headphones/comments/25cmtm/possible_solution_to_the_beats_audio_**bleep**ty_eq/) about it, but it's still not clear what registry keys we should change trying to make the equalizer work.

Does anybody have any thoughts or ideas regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem to me, equalizer does not work and bad audio quality.
***(this Answer don't fix the equalizer , disable all beats audio enhancements for a better audio)***

This helped me a lot with Crap HP driver.

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/beats-audio-bugs-can-t-disable-bass-treble-messed-up-every/td-p/2808815

1) install latest driver ﻿Driver audio IDT 6.10.6491.0 2015/09 sp63555.exe (Still Really Buggy ...)

2) apply reg path to disable "enhancements".

3) Restore Tone Bass/treble at 0 in standard windows audio control panel.

After many attempts, Finnaly a good audio !

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\FFT]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\SpeakerMgr]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\SpeexRef]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Compressor]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Eq]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\FFT]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\HPTone]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Limiter]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SpeakerMgr]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SpeexRef]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SysEq]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\LFX\DockHpOut\plugins\Placeholder]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\LFX\LineOut\plugins\SRS]
"load"=dword:00000000

Comment: One question: Where do you find the latest versions of the Beats Audio software?

Comment: From hp support http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp63501-64000/sp63555.exe

Comment: It's a direct link, but how to find the latest driver using search, etc.? And are you sure it is compatible with the hardware I have in my laptop? BTW, the version number of my BeatsAudio is 6.10.6492.0, but the date is 2013.09.04. Two years older, but the version is greater.

Comment: When I launch sp63555, I see this in the installation wizard: "EFFECTIVE DATE: September 24, 2013". However, after installing, when I open the Beats Audio control panel, I see this in the About box: "6.10.6491.0/2013.08.16". Is there a way to find a newer version of the drivers? Maybe, not on the HP support portal?

Comment: original link for my pc. http://support.hp.com/it-it/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-17-j100-notebook-pc-series/5401174/model/6786951#Z7_3054ICK0K8UDA0AQC11TA930O2 Driver audio IDT ad alta definizione (HD)
 6.10.6491.0 Rev. 44.0 MB 15 set 2015

Comment: Look also at more fresh versions I found the links to on [tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15490-idt-audio-drivers-6504-6492-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but my SOLUTION is for those having an old, but still decent, HP Laptop, with IDT Beats Audio, upgraded to Windows 10 and lost (like me) all the IDT Equalizer functionality.
My setup consists of HP ENVY 17 Leap Motion with Windows 10 x64 and IDT Beats Audio with driver v.6.10.6491.0 from HP site, installed.
After many different approaches I found out that **if I make changes to the red Equalizer sliders in the "listening experience" page and then go to "volume" page and click the little square Phone Icon in "Communication Headphones" and then check back again the little square in "Speakers / HP", the Equalizer settings take effect!!**
The only drawback is that you can not make Equalizer changes in real time, so that you can hear the results while moving the sliders.
Still, better than NO Equalizer...
I hope this solution is applicable to someone else as well and helps.
Alex